# Exporting PDF related from content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i export content from one div, it's only export in 1 page and other content couldn't be seen.

I have 2 divs, one is empty and one is full. The empty one should be filled and exported as PDF. When I export it as PDF, my PDF file only have 1 page and a lot of content is lost. So, I need to have number of pages that is enough for whole content in that div

HTML

```
<div  id="content2"  class="innDiv">
<div  class="aaaL el"> <h2> Sarajevo </h2> </div>
<div  class="aaaL el"> <h2> Mostar </h2> </div>
<div  class="aaaL el"> <h2> Tuzla </h2> </div>
</div>

<div  id="content">
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };


    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('lista.pdf');
    });
  </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.el").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("aaaL")) {
        $this.removeClass("aaaL").addClass("aaaR").prependTo("#content2");
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("aaaR").addClass("aaaL").prependTo("#content");
    }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Need to explain problem in more detail. Right now it is not very clear. See [ask]

Comment: I have 2 divs, one is empty and one is full. The empty one should be filled and exported as PDF. When I export it as PDF, my PDF file only have 1 page and a lot of content is lost. 
So, I need to have number of pages that is enough for whole content in that div... @charlietfl

Comment: ok...suggest you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43353068/edit) with all that detail so it is clear to all readers